# Как в Андроид Студио создать онлайн режим?

Tags: java, android, сеть, клиент-сервер

Как в `Андроид Студио` создать онлайн режим, например шашки онлайн или тому подобное. Примерно хотя бы в каком направлении двигаться?
Понятно, что в двух словах не ответить, но хотя бы в каком работать. 
Я так предполагаю, что сервер в `google`, может есть разработчики, которые уже создавали подобные приложение. Да в гугле пробовал найти, но дело в том, что не совсем понятно, что именно искать, как сформировать вопрос. В результатах поиска выдает не нужные онлайн конструкторы..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одной только `Android Studio` будет явно недостаточно. Вам потребуется также и сервер (желательно свой, т.к. шаг влево-вправо от стороннего решения упрётся в невозможность реализации без адовых костылей).

Примерный план создания подобного такой:

1. Арендуется сервер с выделенным IP. Это к хостерам, выбирать надо VPS/VDS.
2. На сервер арендованный ставятся программы-контейнеры. Например `Tomcat` для `Java-Servlet`.
3. Пишется программа-сервер. Использовать надо технологию сокетов (не голых, а один из протоколов, типа `WebSocket`). Так вы сможете держать открытое двустороннее соединение между сервером и клиентами и обмениваться данными. На сервере надо написать логику передачи данных от одного клиента другому через этот самый сервер. Т.е. один клиент шлёт информацию на сервер, а сервер передаёт её другому клиенту.
4. Клиент должен подсоединиться к серверу и слать/принимать информацию.

Если вы будете писать нативное приложение под андроид, то и для сервера будет разумно использовать Java/Kotlin и использовать голые `Servlet`-ы (просто в освоении, неудобно при серьёзном использовании) или использовать `Spring` - сложный комбайн для сборки сервера (сложен в освоении, но потрясает возможностями; работает на `Servlet`-ах).

Если свой сервер писать не хочется - можно использовать сторонние решения. Например `Firebase`. Но там очень много минусов. Только минимальное использование бесплатно, много ограничений, много неудобств в использовании и, главное, это продукт от гугла, а они - корпорация зла, не стоит на них как-то завязываться.

Comment: Спасибо, примерно буду хоть понимать как это работает и какую информацию нужно искать.

Comment: То что они  - корпорация зла, полностью согласен)) Аккаунт разработчика уже заблокировали.
Вначале приложение заблокировали, после того как написал в техподдержку, аккаунт заблокировали так, что лучше им не писать. 
Но проблема в том, что выкладывать приложение все равно у них придется, альтернативы к сожалению достойной нет

Comment: А что они в причинах по поводу удаления и блокировки писали в вашем случае? Если интересно как они к разработчикам относятся - посмотрите их вебинар недавний для разработчиков - сразу становится понятно за кого они нас держат: https://youtu.be/8yKI-igsWVE

Comment: Я уже не помню,  WebView вроде нельзя вставлять, но получилось так, что я создал несколько приложений и в один день их загрузил и везде использовал по не знаю этот WebView код и они удалили сразу несколько приложений, после того как им написал удалили и аккаунт, и предупредили чтобы я не создавал больше аккаунтов. Обидно, что там около 50-ти приложений было загружено. Вот уже год не загружаю туда ничего, пока опасаюсь, хотя приложение абсолютно безобидные были

Comment: @Artsait, понятно( Они совсем озверели в последнее время. Нет, чтобы нормальную премодерацию и тех.поддержку сделать с живими людьми... Вместо этого роботы просто трут всё подряд и потом и поговорить не с кем на эту тему и заранее не предупреждают. В итоге всё придёт к тому, что их монополистами признают и законодательно обяжут себя прилично вести, но это годы займёт, а пока только один способ правды добиться - шумиха в прессе, да суды, что тоже долго и дорого(

Comment: @Artsait а WebView разве запрещен?

Comment: @danilshik я так понял, что да. Хотя нигде в правилах у них этого не видел. Одно из приложений было карта DayZ, где я с помощью WebView подгружал карту с сайта на Андроид, вторая проверяла есть ли штрафы тоже подгружал данные с сайта с помощью  WebView и третье анекдоты. Вначале создал все эти три программы и в один день все их загрузил и все приложение удалили. В письме от них было что-то связано с WebView, точно не помню по английский было написано, переводил с помощью переводчика

Comment: @Artsait, скорее всего причиной было то, что запрещены приложения, вся суть которых - отображение информации с сайта в WebView. Если это не основная фича, и WebView используется только иногда, частично, для авторизации только, например, то использовать его можно. Суть запрета - зачем приложение, если можно сайт открыть и ничего не поменяется.

Comment: Я так и понял, но на тот момент, я этого не знал, я как бы вообще не думал, что могут заблокировать разработчика. Если бы они блокировали просто аккаунт, это было бы не страшно, человек бы понял где он ошибся и в будущем не повторял бы этого, но они блокируют именно человека

Comment: А у вас приложения удаляли или блокировали? Это 2 разных пути. Первый не очень страшен, т.к. установки-отзывы остаются и можно приложение перевыпустить в виде обновления. А вот второе - гораздо хуже. Приложение не восстановить и эта мера - пятно на аккаунте. Если их несколько - акк удаляют. Да, с этим ничего не сделаешь - они не предупреждают и сразу банят. Но не человека, а их представление о человека в их системе. Много случаев, когда акки компаний банили за то, что у них работал человек с забаненным аккаунтом. Т.е. если они видят связи - всех автоматом банят.

Comment: Вот, может пригодится - чат в телеге, где пострадавшие болтают: https://t.me/android_developers_ban

Comment: Нет, добавить обновление нельзя было, по этому и написал им, чтобы дали такую возможность, исправить приложения. 
Ну вот и непонятно какие у них возможности, если к примеру создать аккаунт другого человека и оплатить 25 дол. (или сколь там сейчас) с его карты, вычислят они связь или нет. Читал, что есть такие люди которые та и делают

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92063/discussion-between-artsait-and-).