# Реализация онлайна

Tags: android, android-studio, https

Не так давно я научился посылать обычные https запросы и в своем приложении сделал онлайн таблицу. Но мне этого не хватает и **я хотел бы сделать соревнование онлайн между двумя игроками**, на теории я примерно предполагаю как это сделать, но на практике пока что  не хватает более детальной информации. **Сам процесс соревнования должен происходить на сервере с задержкой ~2сек, и синхронно каждые ~2сек (с  максимально минимальной задержкой) должен посылаться json двум игрокам с данными, но как сделать все синхронно? В какие технологии копать?**

Comment: Возможно вам этот ответ подойдёт? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/966059/17609

Comment: А есть вариант использовать вместо java servlet к примеру php?

Comment: По идее да. Недавно тут где-то был вопрос и в комментах писали, что можно сокеты использовать на php. Типа есть какая-то либа под это дело.

Comment: Ну я про сокеты слышал, и чаще всего использовали javascript. Но хотелось бы задать возможно глупый вопрос на тему сокетов, один веб-сокет это же по идее один отдельный сервер? И что-бы два соревнования   проходили одновременно требуется два отдельных vps сервера? Я просто в этой теме не до конца разобрался.

Comment: Обычно используют реализацию протокола (WebSocket) на нужном языке, т.е. оно есть почти под все языки, не обязательно JavaScript. Нет, оно работает так: Сервер принимает запрос на соединение с клиентом и обменивается с ним данными. Клиентов может быть сколько угодно (почти, конечно если одновременно подключатся тысячи - будут проблемы, но сотни одновременных подключений должны нормально обрабатываться). При этом сервер должен содержать логику определяющую сообщения какого клиента отправить какому клиенту/клиентам. Т.е. нужен один сервер для всех клиентов.

Comment: Спасибо, туман в моем сознании исчез

Comment: Как вы смотрите на то, чтобы закрыть вопрос как дубль того, что я в первой ссылке привёл?

Comment: Да мне в принципе все равно